# Link items to categories in a list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The context of my problem is that I have to lists:

- One list of categories
- One list of items

The number of categories/items in both list can vary, as well as their order in it.

[image: example for the two lists]

My problem is that I want to implement 2 possible types of actions:

- The first action is to be able to assign each item to one or more categories. For example, I am the user of the excel sheet and I want to assign item 3 to categories 1, 2 and 4 (via checkbox or other means).
- The second action is to be able to highlight all the items in a category by selecting this category (either select the cell or the category in a dropdown list). For example, is items 1 an 3 belong to category 1, we would have the following results when selecting category 1:
  [image: Resulting view when selecting category 1]

I would like to realize this in an excel spreadsheet with VBA macro. I tried to find technical solutions in order to implement this but without success. Indeed, I would need to link variables to a cell (in order to assign categories to item) but I found no way to do that (classical use of variables and arrays are too restricted for the requirements).

My questions are therefore:

- Do you think the proposed application is implementable in excel (potentially with VBA) ?
- Do you have ideas of what technical solutions I could use in order to implement it so that I have a starting point to solve my problem ?

Comment: Yes - you can do it with VBA and a dropdown combo box that does the highlighting for you. Start with building some basic macros and looking at the resulting code. You can also google and search SO for examples

Comment: The things that is a real problem for me for the moment is how to keep in memory the categories linked to each items. Indeed simple variables can not allow me to do that because I need to keep in memory a variable size list of categories for each cell in the items list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use excel as a 2-entries array to assign items to categories; then use conditional formatting:

[image]

Maybe its too simple for your case, but it can help somebody else.

Comment: That is indeed too simple but it can be a first step to implement that. I used you structure to stored that correspondance between item and categories in a second (hidden) sheet. Then with some macro, I manage the user interface by using event functions (when the users select some cell in the sheet).